# Add second image upload tab for products

Tags: magento2, product-images

How do I create a second image upload tab for products similar to default one? I only need to upload images and so that they belong to that product.

I need this so that I can fetch those images in a template and display them in image gallery.

Has anyone done something similar or know how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create new attribute of Media Image type. Then assign it to attribute set, reindex and refresh cache. Then we can add media images through the section "Images and Videos". After uploading the image, just click on that image and specify it as an attribute image.

Comment: You can assign it to only one image... I already tried that and it doesn't work for this at all.